# How do I export Wikipedia article collections to epub?

Tags: wikipedia, export

I used to do that a year or two ago and it was pretty straightforward back than (there was «Export to epub» link or something like this on the left pane of a Wikipedia page). Not any more! Currently, there are two options for export in the book creator, namely, «pdf» and «plain text» (only «pdf» for single article).

What is worth I did not manage to find any clear info on why it is not there. The article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Tools#PDF.2C_EPub.2C_Odt_and_LaTeX mentions it is still possible to produce epubs and re-directs to some weird page.

Do I miss anything obvious or they really disabled this useful functionality for good?

Answer (score 2):

The wired page was written by me. It links to the following page, where you can put in a link to a wikipedia article and download the corresponding epub file.
http://mediawiki2latex.wmflabs.org/
Greetings from the cowshed.
Yours Dirk

Comment: Then I'm pleased to have an opportunity to say «Thank you Dirk for your generous attempt to remedy the situation» directly. If you feel stinged with my word «weird» I take it back. What I meant was the fact your solution is a provisional one (needless to say, I had tested the tool, before I wrote my original post).

Comment: I have three questions for you as the author of that code:
1) Do you have plans to compile your tool for Windows (unfortunately, it is a matter of fact, the great majority of people on Earth use Windows, not Linux)? Setting up a Linux virtual machine is a bit of overkill, is it?
2) Is there any way to export collections of e-pubs from Wikipedia with your tool?
3) I guess you keep contact with Wikipedia people. So you may know when they plan to re-enable the export to e-pub and zim as an integral part of the Wikipedia engine (well, if they are going to do it at all in the first place).

Comment: 1) I have and old version for windows on sourceforge. Unfortunately the gui does not work anymore on recent patch levels of windows 7. Also the only possible output formats of that version are latex and pdf but not epub. For me it takes several days to install windows 7 and download and install all patches, so that I currently don't use windows at all. 2) You can not directly exports wikipedia collection books. But you can make one page on the wiki that includes all article you  want to export: wiki syntax like {{:MyArticle}} 3) I don't expect the wiki foundation to come up with anything soon.

Comment: here is the link to the old windows version https://sourceforge.net/projects/wb2pdf/files/mediawiki2latex/7.21/

Comment: I added a new runmode to work with tghe wikipedia book namespace. It acivates itself as soon as the given url contains the string "Book:". I testet it with the following url https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book:River_martin

Comment: In order to test your new runmode, I have created a Wikipedia account, but it looks like at the moment I can't create books in the «Book» namespace (frankly, I am not familiar with Wikipedia internals and «MyArticle» is not on the list of spacenames), until I do some editing job. The book you referred to has been converted nicely indeed, but I am eager to try your tool against collections of articles on topics in mathematics. So, if it is not difficult, could you, please, implement ability to process books in the «User:» namespace as well?

Comment: in the combo box "Template Expansion" select "Book Mode"

Comment: This tool seems dead.

Comment: according to the statistics people are still using it https://qa.debian.org/popcon.php?package=mediawiki2latex also the website is still reachable, still sometimes you might have to wait until your request can be processed on the main server. But there is also the large document server that seems to have lower traffic at the moment http://mediawiki2latex-large.wmflabs.org/